# Java, JNI and Class declarations

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Can any JNI expert explain the following situation, as i cannot wrap my head around the issue.

Say we have this class:

```
public class MyClass {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("recorder");
    }

    private native long function1();    
    private native void function2();

    private void callback() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MyClass obj1 = new MyClass();
        obj1.function1();
    }

}
```

in JNI (C):

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL function1(JNIEnv *env, jobject object) {
   jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, object);
   jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "callback", "()V");

   if (mid != NULL) {
        (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, object, mid);
   }
}
```

This works fine, however, if instead of

```
private native long function1();
```

i declare

```
private static native long function1();
```

the call from JNI to Java fails complaining it cannot find the function callback in Java.

Thanks

Comment: I bet that when you call static version of `function1()`, `object` argument is NULL. Hence, `cls` is also NULL and `mid` is also NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For static native method the second argument in native code should not be the `jobject` but `jclass`.

But you should rather generate c headers with `javah` tool rather than writing them manually.

Comment: Technically not correct. On the C side `jobject` and `jclass` are just defines for the same thing. Doesn't make a difference. The actual problem is the equivalent of the "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method" compiler message. If `function1` is static you can't access non-static `callback` from it, because there is no object.

Comment: @user2543253 He is saying the value is wrong, not that the types are incompatible. The reason for the different but same types is to make that as strong of a hint as possible.

Comment: @Tom not sure if he's actually saying the value is wrong. Nothing about objects and classes in the answer but instead there's the part about always using `javah` to generate headers. That would be my advice too, but I doubt it would have helped here, because it seems the OP added the `static` later on and would probably not have noticed that the declaration changed from `jobject` to `jclass` because it still compiles ...